# Expanding heirarchial data, creating new rows based on list item in column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nested, hierarchy

How can I expand a dataframe, based on the conditionals provided with respect to the nesting of groups like below?

groups

```
Name                    Job        Group
[Matt,Adam,John,James]  Peon       Workers
[Sam,Andrew,John]       Boss       Leader
[Leader,Ian]            Owner      Owner
```

How can I make the expected output like below:

Expected Output:

```
Name    Job       Group
Matt    Peon      Workers
Adam    Peon      Workers
John    Peon      Workers
James   Peon      Workers
Sam     Boss      Leader
Andrew  Boss      Leader
John    Boss      Leader
Sam     Owner     Owner
Andrew  Owner     Owner
John    Owner     Owner
Ian     Owner     Owner
```

My current method (not working fully) extracts all users, but does not identify the members that are also equal to a group name and create a new entry for each member.

```
groups.members.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x)).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).to_frame('members').join(groups[['Job', 'Group']], how='left')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this can be done entirely in pandas. I have processed the relevant data externally, afterwards I rejoined it.

```
import pandas as pd

groups = pd.DataFrame({'Name': [['Matt','Adam','John','James'], ['Sam','Andrew','John', 'Boss']], 'Job': ['Peon', 'Owner'], 'Group': ['Boss', 'Leader']})

# Build a list of tuples with row to draw group and job from and name
x = [(idx, i) for idx, j in enumerate(groups['Name']) for i in j]

# Search the list for group names, if found resolve group 
# names to additional members of row where group was found
for i, j in x:
    if j in set(groups.Group):
            x.remove((i, j))
            for n in list(*list(groups['Name'][groups.Group == j])):
                x.append((i, n))

# Create new DataFrame
idx, names = zip(*x)
z = pd.DataFrame(list(names), index=list(idx))

# Join on the old one
groups = groups.drop('Name', axis=1).join(z)
```

Comment: What is the name of the Group column in your dataframe? If you adjust it, it should work.

Comment: Could you post a short example where you construct your dataframe?

Comment: It was an error on my part. This worked great thank you!

Answer (score 1):

## `pandas`

```
df.set_index(
    ['Group', 'Job']
).Name.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index([0, 1], name='Name')

     Group    Job    Name
0  Workers   Peon    Matt
1  Workers   Peon    Adam
2  Workers   Peon    John
3  Workers   Peon   James
0   Leader   Boss     Sam
1   Leader   Boss  Andrew
2   Leader   Boss    John
0    Owner  Owner  Leader
1    Owner  Owner     Ian
```

## `numpy`

```
name = df.Name.values.tolist()
i = np.arange(len(df)).repeat([len(l) for l in name])

pd.DataFrame(
    np.hstack([np.concatenate(name)[:, None], df.drop('Name', 1).values[i]]),
    df.index[i], df.columns)
```

---

***naive timing***

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another `numpy solution`:

```
from  itertools import chain

lens = df.Name.str.len()
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        "Job": np.repeat(df.Job.values, lens),
         "Group": np.repeat(df.Group.values, lens),
        "Name": list(chain.from_iterable(df.Name))})
print (df1)
     Group    Job    Name
0  Workers   Peon    Matt
1  Workers   Peon    Adam
2  Workers   Peon    John
3  Workers   Peon   James
4   Leader   Boss     Sam
5   Leader   Boss  Andrew
6   Leader   Boss    John
7    Owner  Owner  Leader
8    Owner  Owner     Ian
```

**Timings** - compare only fastest numpy solutions:

```
import random
import string
from  itertools import chain

np.random.seed(123)
N = 100000
L1 = ['Peon','Boss','Owner']
L2 = ['Workers','Leader','Owner']
Jobs = np.random.choice(L1, N)
Groups = np.random.choice(L2, N)
Name = [list(tuple(string.ascii_letters[:random.randint(3, 10)])) for _ in range(N)]
df = pd.DataFrame({"Job":Jobs,"Group":Groups, "Name":Name})
#[100000 rows x 3 columns]
#print (df)
```

```
def jez(df):
    lens = df.Name.str.len()
    return pd.DataFrame({
            "Job": np.repeat(df.Job.values, lens),
            "Group": np.repeat(df.Group.values, lens),
            "Name": list(chain.from_iterable(df.Name))})

def pir(df):
    name = df.Name.values.tolist()
    i = np.arange(len(df)).repeat([len(l) for l in name])

    return pd.DataFrame(
        np.hstack([np.concatenate(name)[:, None], df.drop('Name', 1).values[i]]),
        df.index[i], df.columns)

print (pir(df))
print (jez(df))

%timeit (pir(df))
1 loop, best of 3: 267 ms per loop

%timeit (jez(df))
10 loops, best of 3: 94 ms per loop
```

Comment: I like this!  I tried mine a little different this time.  Never bothered to check which would be quicker.

Comment: Yes, in smaller df it is different I guess.

Answer (score 0):

try this (name your dataframe as df):

```
a=pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.name.tolist()).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).rename('name')
df.drop('name', axis=1).join(a).reset_index(drop=True)[['name','job','Group']]
```

Comment: @johnnyb did you try this?

Comment: I did ran into some errors, will give it another attempt in the am